# An empty block instead of a html video element in React until I click on the block on mobile devices (Iphone)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

**I'm developing a web application using Next.js, and I have a carousel of video players on the page. Here's how it looks:**

```
export default function CustomerReviewsCarousel({ reviews }: Props) {


const { width } = useScreenSize();
  const [activeVideoIndex, setActiveVideoIndex] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [isPlay, setIsPlay] = useState(false);

  function handlePlayClick(index: number) {
    const video = document.getElementById(
      `review-video-${activeVideoIndex}`
    ) as HTMLVideoElement;

    if (activeVideoIndex === index) {
      if (isPlay) {
        setIsPlay(false);
      } else {
        setIsPlay(true);
      }
    } else {
      if (video) {
        video.pause();
        video.currentTime = 0;
      }
      setIsPlay(true);
      setActiveVideoIndex(index);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = document.getElementById(
      `review-video-${activeVideoIndex}`
    ) as HTMLVideoElement;

    if (isPlay) {
      video?.play();
    } else {
      video?.pause();
    }
  }, [isPlay, activeVideoIndex]);

  return (
    <Carousel
      opts={{
        loop: true,
        align: width > 840 ? "start" : "center",
      }}
      className="static"
    >
      <CarouselContent className="h-full">
        {reviews.map((item, idx) => (
          <CarouselItem
            key={idx}
            className="group relative sm:basis-1/2 2xl:basis-1/3"
          >
            <div className="relative">
              <video
                id={`review-video-${idx}`}
                className={cn(
                  "bg-white/60",
                  "h-[410px] w-full object-cover rounded-[10px] z-[0]"
                )}
                loop
                controls={false}
                playsInline
              >
                <source src={item} />
              </video>
              <button
                onClick={() => handlePlayClick(idx)}
                className={cn(
                  "absolute z-[20] top-[50%] translate-y-[-50%] left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] p-[20px] rounded-full bg-[rgba(255,255,255,0.20)] backdrop-blur-lg",
                  activeVideoIndex === idx &&
                    isPlay &&
                    "invisible opacity-activeVideoIndex transition-all ease-in-out group-hover:opacity-100 group-hover:visible"
                )}
              >
                {activeVideoIndex === idx && isPlay ? (
                  <PauseIcon className="text-white relative" />
                ) : (
                  <PlayIcon className="text-white relative left-[2px]" />
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </CarouselItem>
        ))}
      </CarouselContent>
      <div className="absolute left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] bottom-[70px] w-[112px]">
        <CarouselPrevious className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-[48px] h-[48px]" />
        <CarouselNext className="absolute top-0 right-0 w-[48px] h-[48px]" />
      </div>{" "}
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```

On mobile phones, I'm experiencing an issue where white blocks appear instead of the videos, presumably due to specifying bg-white/60, and nothing else is visible. However, when I tap on these white blocks, the video appears or loads. On desktop, everything works fine; the videos load and display correctly, but on iPhones, they don't.

[image]
[image]

Also i have tried make custom video component with ref control, but it still white block on iphone (on android its fine) until i tap:

```
export default function CustomVideo({ src }: Props) {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
  const [isPlay, setIsPlay] = useState(false);

  function handlePlayClick() {
    if (ref.current) {
      if (isPlay) {
        ref.current.pause();
        setIsPlay(false);
      } else {
        ref.current.play();
        setIsPlay(true);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <video
        ref={ref}
        className={cn(
          "bg-white/60",
          "h-[410px] w-full object-cover rounded-[10px] z-[0]"
        )}
        loop
        controls={false}
        playsInline
      >
        <source src={src} />
      </video>
      <button
        onClick={handlePlayClick}
        className={cn(
          "absolute z-[20] top-[50%] translate-y-[-50%] left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] p-[20px] rounded-full bg-[rgba(255,255,255,0.20)] backdrop-blur-lg",

          isPlay &&
            "invisible opacity-activeVideoIndex transition-all ease-in-out group-hover:opacity-100 group-hover:visible"
        )}
      >
        {isPlay ? (
          <PauseIcon className="text-white relative" />
        ) : (
          <PlayIcon className="text-white relative left-[2px]" />
        )}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please make a minimal example which we can run and which shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, have you checked that there are no settings on the iPhone which prevent loading a video before there is some user interaction?